# Could not find mutate and svytable function

Tags: r

I am running my r code in R markdown and I'm getting an error message:

> Could not find function mutate, `%>%` and `svytable`.

I already ran the libraries:

```
library(tidyverse)
library (dplyr)
library(pander)
library(survey)
library(janitor)
library(broom)
library(knitr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
```

And I am still get error message. Anyone please help.

Comment: Start a new session and run `library(dplyr)`. What does the message say?

Comment: Be aware that markdown documents are knitted in a fresh environment. If you don't have those lines in the document, you will end up with that error.

Comment: There's like an error message that printed out at some point if it can't find the functions. Double check that no error message are present. Show the output of `sessionInfo()` after you run all those library commands. Did you include the `library()` calls in the Markdown document itself?

Comment: I started a new environment to run the code and now I have a bunch of errors like Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘ellipsis’ 0.3.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.2 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.0.5

Comment: If you see "package or namespace load failed", that means it cannot load the package. Try reinstalling the package. If you see the messages "is already loaded" then something is loaded the pacakge for you which is preventing you from updating it. Usually starting a new R session should not load any packages. But if you have a .Rprofile file or some other `?Startup` file that auto-loads things for you, you'll want to be sure to disable that so you can update the package.

Comment: how would I update R studio?

Comment: Updating RStudio won't help with this. It won't change your packages at all. Those are all managed by R. RStudio is just an IDE that makes it easier to use R.

Comment: It says the packages are already loaded when I run the code Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘ellipsis’ 0.3.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.2 is required.